# Error using $wpdb->prepare()

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

**I'm trying to use $wpdb->prepare() function but it is returning an error. What is wrong with the SQL syntax?**

WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''wp_spreadsheets' WHERE id = 6' at line 1]

```
SELECT table_name, table_code FROM 'wp_spreadsheets' WHERE id = 6
```

The code I'm using is as followed.

```
<?php

// Variables
$mysqltable_name = 'wp_spreadsheets';
$table_id = 6;

// Query
$query = $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT table_name, table_code FROM %s WHERE id = %d', $mysqltable_name, $table_id );
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );

// Results
if( !empty( $results ) ) {
    print_r( $results );
} else {
    $wpdb->print_error();
}

?>
```

Comment: You can't bind table names and column names, only variables.

Answer (score 1):

`%s` means that you intend to use a `varchar` input, which is nice on your PHP end where you pass the `$mysqltable_name` text, but on MySQL level the query to be executed will contain apostrophes around `$mysqltable_name` since it is a `varchar`. You need to use string concatenation or hard-coded table name to avoid it in your PHP code. If your `table` name is dynamic, then you need to make sure it will not contain harmful code.